# Como centro toda la div que este al centro de la pagina

Tags: html, css

he estado haciendo una pagina y hice un cuadro pero quiero que ese cuadro este en el centro total de la pagina y intento pero se queda en el centro y la mitad hacia la izquierda y tanbien quiero que ocupe casi toda la pagina.

el codigo es
HTML

```
<div class="cuadroxd">
     <h1>Hola *xd*, </h1>
      <h2> texto :v </h2>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.cuadroxd {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 0.5em;

  border: solid 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,207,48,0.5) 0%, rgba(254,255,0,0.5) 100%);
  color: #fff; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  left 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

y bueno eso quien me quiera ayudar puede comentar

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            align-items     : center;
            display         : flex;
            height          : 100vh;
            justify-content : center;
        }
        .cuadroxd {
           background     : linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,207,48,0.5) 0%, rgba(254,255,0,0.5) 100%);
           border         : solid 2px;
           border-radius  : 10px;
           color          : #fff;
           padding        : 5px 5px 5px 0.5em;
           text-decoration: none;

           height : 80%;
           width  : 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="container">
    <div class="cuadroxd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes usar ***flex en el contenedor*** del div que quieres centrar, le aplico un height de `100vh` para que use el 100% del alto de la página y centre el div en la página verticalmente.

Comment: Hola, Orita en pc lo pruebo. con centrado me refiero en horizontal y rn vertical que quede un cuadrado o rectangulo en el centro de la pagina y thx.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes un error en la declaración de tus estilos en cascada: sólo agrega los dos puntos al final de la palabra `left`.

```
.cuadroxd {
  ...
  left: 50%;
  ...
}
```

Así debería funcionar correctamente:

```
.cuadroxd {
           padding: 5px 5px 5px 0.5em;

           border: solid 2px;
           border-radius: 10px;
           background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,207,48,0.5) 0%, rgba(254,255,0,0.5) 100%);
           color: #fff; 
           text-decoration: none; 
             
           width: 80%;
           height: 80%;
           position: absolute;
           left: 50%;
           top: 50%;
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
           
      }
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Ah si era eso pero ahora se pone de el centro hasta el borde de la derecha, me podrias ayudar en esto?